# Multi dimensional grid for general number of dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I need to generate a grid for an array with a general/variable number of dimensions. In the 2D case, I know I can use [mgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html):

```
# Some 2D data
N = 1000
x = np.random.uniform(0., 1., N)
y = np.random.uniform(10., 100., N)
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()

# Obtain 2D grid
xy_grid = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:10j, ymin:ymax:10j]
```

How can I scale this approach when the number of dimensions is variable? Ie: my data could be `(x, y)` or `(x, y, z)` or `(x, y, z, q)`, etc.

The naive approach of:

```
# Md_data.shape = (M, N), for M dimensions
dmin, dmax = np.amin(Md_data, axis=1), np.amax(Md_data, axis=1)
Md_grid = np.mgrid[dmin:dmax:10j]
```

does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a list comprehension looping through the list of variables : `x,y,z,q,etc.` to create the slice notation and then simply feed it to `mgrid` -

```
L = [x,y,z,q] # list of variables
out = np.mgrid[[np.s_[A.min():A.max():10j] for A in L]]
```

With the `slice` constructor :

```
np.mgrid[[slice(A.min(),A.max(),10j) for A in L]]
```